# How to Insert German setup base price module in different list views

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to use the German setup base price module, which is shown at the product view. I want to use it in all list views too.

[image: Base price module]

[image]

The template, I am using, has a **subprice.phtml**, which is used for all product views (listing, grids, cart).
How can I manage to display the base price there too?

Comment: without knowing which module you are using and how the module returns the base price data it is hard to answer this. Perhaps contacting the module author and asking them how to include the base price data in the list view would help.

Comment: I tried to contact the author- no reply! What must I post to clear it up?

Answer (score 1):

Use the documentation at http://de.nr-apps.com/store/hilfeseiten/hilfe/baseprice.html

It says:

To assign the output to your grid and list view, please use following code inside your file:

```
app/design/frontend/IHR_PAKET/IHR_TEMPLATE/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

---

```
<?php if($baseprice = Mage::helper('baseprice')->getBasePriceLabel($_product, true)): ?>
    <div class="baseprice">(<?php echo $baseprice ?>)</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```